# QGIS Georeferencer is stretching image

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, stretch

I'm trying to Georeference an image. I've followed the guide from QGIS, but for some reason, it's stretching, and offsetting the image from the points.

For example, my input of the southwest corner is:

```
49.729628
98.471569
```

And after I've run the georeferencer the southwest corner is:

```
49.7312
98.9994
```

Both the image, and the georeferencer are using `WGS 84 EPSG:4326` as the CRS.

You can see the input, the settings and output below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other transformation methods than linear?

Answer (score 4):

Your picture is stretched, because you have chosen a geographic CRS (WGS84) as project CRS. Far away from the equator, one degree of longitude is smaller than one degree of latitude.

Set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857. Google uses the same for its imagery, though it displays coordinates in degrees.

BTW for Manitoba, use negative values for longitudes west of Greenwich. And you can load Google imagery directly into QGIS with the QuickMapServices plugin, if you add `More services -> Get contributed pack` in the settings.